# What is the Big O of such an algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

If you had code that looks like this, what would the big O be? I'm uncertain as to how `if` statements affect big O.

```
n = some arbitrary number
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
  for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
    if(i <= j)
      for(k = i; k <= j; k++)
        //do some simple operation
        y = x+1
    else
        //do some simple operation
        y = y+1
```

I'm not considering compiler optimizations. I know this is somewhere between O(n^2) and O(n^3) but am not sure as the if statement does not always execute the inner most loop.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, what is your explination?

Comment: Seriously, 3 downvotes and no explanation?

Comment: If you are satisfied any of the answers (below) to your question, please consider [marking the question as answered to close it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). I see from your history of questions that you haven't accepted an answer for any of your recent questions; in fact, for you last 20 questions (to which there exists at least one answer), you've accepted only one. Please consider going through your numerous questions, to either accept them, or give feedback to answerers to see if they can help you out further. ...->

Comment: This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is of course no obligation to do this, but it can be helpful to future visitors to see which answers (if there are many) that you as OP considered to answer your question.

Comment: @dfri for questions such as this one it's hard to select a right answer as technically any that said O(N^3) is right and which one explained the clearest is a matter of opinion.

Comment: I agree that this is sometimes the case; the above was mostly a general note regarding the numerous un-accepted answers in your Question history. But again, it's no obligation to accept answers!

Comment: @dfri ya thanks for the reminder, it did seem I had forgotten a few.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O(N * N * N) which we can just say is O(N^3)

First Loop happens N times.
Second Loop happens N times. 
Those multiply together to get O(N^2)

Out of all the possible N^2 loops, the third loop would run about half the time, which is O(N/2) which is equivalent to O(N).

And that's how you get O(N * N * N) or O(N^3)

Comment: Oh right, even if third loop runs a fraction of the time, big O notation discards a constant multiple. Is that your reasoning?

Comment: Yep, unless you care about nitty gritty detail you leave off partials and insignificant values. So you'll rarely see things like O(n^2 + 1).

The simple operations like y = x+1 and the if-else clauses are assumed to be O(1) and don't factor into the time so much.

Comment: First loop runs N times without fail, always doing some amount of work. For each iteration of first loop, second loop runs N times, without fail, at minimum performing work just once for a lower bound of O(N^2). However, there is a condition where the third loop will run from i to j, which is <= N, allowing us to safely give an upper bound of O(N^3). Probably could give a tighter bound, but O(N^3) is technically correct, and probably good enough for Big-Oh.

Comment: @AndyG that's what I was thinking `O(n^2 * log(n))` but that's not quite right.

Comment: That innermost loop will run (1 + 2 +... +N) = O(N^2) times on the first iteration of the outermost loop. Then it won't run at all. Then it will run (2 + 3 + ... + N-1) = O(N^2) times on the next iteration. then not at all. Then again, etc. until it only runs 1 time. So we have this interesting transition where we lose two elements each time it runs. However, this is a constant, so we still have essentially O(N^2) operations being applied N times, for an upper bound of O(N^3). It's definitely not logarithmic, because the number of elements is not being halved.

Comment: @AndyG hmmm, that's true. Let me know if you think of anything else, I'm interested.

Answer (score 0):

**In fact you can count (almost exactly) how many operations you do:**

i: 0 to n-1 = N operations

x

j:  0 to n-1 = N operations

x

only when i<=j, from i to j, or another task O(1)

The *other* task gives you NxN operations, then O(NxN)

that is, if you invert

for every j (0 to n-1) : N operations

then for every i from 0 to j, you do an operation from i to j, that is j-i+1

exactly the same as every 0 to j operations. Then you have (j+1)x(j+2)/2 operations.

then finally, you get Sum (j+1)x(j+2)/2 from 0 to N which is

**1/2 ((N+1)x(N+2)/2 + (N+1)^3/3+(N+1)^2/2+(N+1)/6) operations, so O(N^3)**

Perhaps, I forgot some +/-1

Answer (score 0):

You can analyse your algorithm using Sigma notation:

[image]

From this, it's obvious the time complexity will depend on cubic `n` terms, and hence your algorithm is in `O(n^3)`.

Answer (score -1):

This is O(N^3).

Proof: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+sum+%28j+-+i+%2B+1%29%2C+j+%3D+i+to+n+-+1%2C+i+%3D+0+to+n+-+1

Last cycle runs `(j - i + 1)` times.

How to find this sum manually?
This is not a rocket math.

Try to read about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series

Just to save time it's easier to use wolframalpha for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain how it's O(N^3)?

Comment: Are you sure about the optimisation? We don't know the type of `y`, it could be any magma. Second, I'm not sure how you got your optimized formula even if we assume numbers. OP's code doesn't modify `x`.

Comment: @JanDvorak He edited the question. Look at earlier version, I corrected my answer.

Comment: I edited because you were considering compiler optimization which was not part of the question.